# Can't Caching WebView when internet connection or not show cache when internet not connection?

Tags: android, webview

I'm implement webview in my app and I want to load cache when not internet offline, but this not works for me. This is my code :

```
....

    pageInfo = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.pageInfo);
            pageInfo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            pageInfo.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            pageInfo.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            pageInfo.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            pageInfo.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            pageInfo.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            pageInfo.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
            pageInfo.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            pageInfo.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 100);
            pageInfo.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);


if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
            pageInfo.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
            Log.w("tag", "offline");
        }
        try {
            pageInfo.loadUrl(Variabel.link_detail_post);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


         }

....

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
```

this my permission

```
 <!--  permission -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

so how to solve this ? thanks .. sorry for my english and grammar

Comment: First of all please check whether your webview has definitly cached the page:

    if (isNetworkAvailable() == true) { 
    
        pageInfo.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
            
    } else {
        
        pageInfo.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
    }
    
    pageInfo.loadUrl(Variabel.link_detail_post);

Comment: thanks for answered, i have do that, but ,,, its still "web page not avaible" if `WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY)`